# Docker Commit Created Images and ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker

How do you ensure that the original CMD specified in your Dockerfile is still set to run on `docker run`, when you make changes via `docker commit`?

Here's the sequence of events, to make it a little clearer:

1. Create image with Dockerfile
2. Run container from image with `-ti --entrypoint /bin/bash` at some point afterwards to make some changes
3. Make changes inside container and run `docker commit` to create new image, with new tag
4. When the new image is run, the original CMD entry from the original Dockerfile is no longer run

So I'm asking; how do you reset the CMD from the Dockerfile again on a committed image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would create a Dockerfile to set the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.  Simply base the Dockerfile on the image id returned by `docker commit`.  For example, given this:

```
$ docker commit $(docker ps -lq)
69e9c08825508ec780efc86268a05ffdf4edae0999a2424dbe36cb04c2a15d6b
```

I could create a Dockerfile that looked like this:

```
FROM 69e9c08825508ec780efc86268a05ffdf4edae0999a2424dbe36cb04c2a15d6b
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

And then use that to build a new image:

```
$ docker build .
Step 0 : FROM 69e9c08825508ec780efc86268a05ffdf4edae0999a2424dbe36cb04c2a15d6b
 ---> 69e9c0882550
Step 1 : CMD /bin/bash
 ---> Running in f886c783551d
 ---> 13a0f8ea5cc5
Removing intermediate container f886c783551d
Successfully built 13a0f8ea5cc5
```

That said, your best course of action is probably to *not* make changes in the container and then use Docker commit; you end up with a much more auditable set of changes if you just rely on the Dockerfile to implement the necessary changes in the first place.

Comment: Yup, I ended up doing pretty much that. Built a new-new image  `FROM` the new image. I'm not very happy with this though.

As for doing everything in the Dockerfile; sometimes that's not possible. In this case for example, the changes I made via a commit relied on files that I could not include in the Dockerfile due to portability (other people would not have them).

Comment: the question is how to do it without Dockerfile, it's very inconvenient if you have to create a Dockerfile each time you want to make a quick change to something

Comment: Speaking from experience, "each time you want to make a quick change to something" soon deteriorates in to "wtf how did I end up with this image and how do I make it from scratch?". It's more tedious to use Dockerfile+version control, but your future you and your colleagues will thank you.

Answer (score 64):

Current Docker versions (I'm on 1.11.1) provide a `--change` option that allow in-line manipulation of the image at commit time, as in:

```
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["myEntryPoint.sh"]' $(docker ps -lq)
```

`CMD` is also supported as are a few others.  See [manpage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) for more details and examples.