# Environment variables in Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up our production environment in a docker image.
After spending some hours compiling software, I realized that I forgot to set the locale environment variables in the Dockerfile.

Is there a way to permanently commit environment variables to an image?
I only came across the dockerfile way of doing this and I don't want to rebuild from that and lose all the work already done.

Setting those variables in `.bashrc` is not working, as the docker run command seems to bypass those settings.

Comment: You _will_ have to rebuild, sooner or later. So you better start working on automating the provisioning.

Comment: What version of docker are you using? On which OS? What `docker run` options are you using?

Comment: @VonC I am using version 1.11.2. At the moment I just attach to the container, do apt-get install, manually compile stuff and commit the changes to my image. I am still learning how to use docker correctly...

Comment: Sure. On which OS?

Comment: @KahPhi Note: you dno't apt-get within a container: you do that once in the Dockerfile and that allows you to run containers with that already installed.

Comment: @VonC I am running Fedora 21 on my machine. The server runs CentOS 6 and my image is based on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to permanently commit environment variables to an image?

That is the [directive `ENV` in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env).

```
ENV <key> <value>
ENV <key>=<value> ...
```

But since you don't want to rebuild the image (although you could add it at the end of the dockerfile, and [benefit from the cache](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/build-cache) for most of the image build), you can still launch your containers with [`docker run -e "variable=value"`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/env-environment-variables)

Comment: In order to add that to my image permanently, it seems the only option is to use FROM {my_image} in the dockerfile and set ENV like described here. Thanks

Comment: @KahPhi True, you can build a new image FROM your existing image.

Answer (score 1):

You can change environment variables during a "docker commit" operation to modify an existing image. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/ and this StackOverflow Q&A: [Docker Commit Created Images and ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015023/docker-commit-created-images-and-entrypoint) - and reference the answer by sxc731. It is not clear to me how one sets multiple Env variables, but it might take a separate --change for each.

Here is an example of what I was just doing (bash shell):

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash $origimghash
# make changes, leave running, then in another shell:
EP='ENTRYPOINT ["python","/tmp/deploy/deploy.py"]'
ENV='Env no_proxy "*.local, 169.254/16"'
docker commit "--change=$ENV" "--change=$EP" $runninghash me/myimg
docker inspect -f "{{ .Config.Env }}" $newhash
```