# docker commit --change entrypoint always fail

Tags: docker

Docker version 1.13.1. Container OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

The only thing I need is to run `php5.6-fpm` through `service php5.6-fpm start`.

I try to commit to image, then create container from that image. Below is what I did (not works):

```
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["service php5.6-fpm start"]' e152c4db5168  myimage/test_image
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/rc.local; ls"]' e152c4db5168  myimage2/test_image
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/rc.local"]' e152c4db5168  myimage3/test_image
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash -c '/etc/rc.local; ls'"]' e152c4db5168  myimage4/test_image
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/testing.sh"]' e152c4db5168  myimage5/test_image
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["mkdir /zzzzzzzzzzz"]' e152c4db5168  myimage6/test_image
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]' -c "/etc/rc.local; ls" e152c4db5168  myimage7/test_image
```

I also tried running my custom `/etc/rc.local` & `/testing.sh` which it doing `mkdir` for testing purposes.

All of them whether cannot commit, or cannot run, or run but no startup service.

My reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293393/8918179, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: you can also try `docker run --entrypoint...` and then `docker commit $(docker ps -lq)  myimage/test_image`

Comment: Thanks for that, .. still working to get the right run entrypoint that works

Comment: So far I can do is `run -ti -d --entrypoint "/usr/bin/php5.6" myimage/test_image` but it gave exit code 137 on stop